# How to programatically select the default Chip in a ChipGroup in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-chips

TL;DR - What is the correct way to programatically select a default choice Chip that is a child of a ChipGroup in Android?

--

In my android app, I am using `com.google.android.material.chip.Chip` styled as `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice` components to represent choices of activities a user can select for a given route (think walk, bike, etc)

Because a route can have different types of activities, I insert each type as a different chip programatically into a `com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup`. I also select the default chip as being the first one inserted in the list using the following code during onViewCreated() of my fragment

```
 private fun setupTypeSelection(types: List<Type>) {
    types.forEach { type ->
        val chip = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chip_type, viewBinding.typeChipGroup, false) as Chip

        chip.tag = type
        /* Init chip text and icon */

        chip.setOnClickListener {
            /* Update selected type */
        }

        if (currentType == null) {
            chip.isSelected = true
            currentType = type
        }

        viewBinding.typeChipGroup.addView(chip)
    }
}
```

Here's the layout definition of the ChipGroup, where a I set single selection, etc

chip_group_layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
      android:id="@+id/type_container"

      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"

      app:chipSpacingHorizontal="@dimen/margin_medium"
      app:selectionRequired="true"
      app:singleLine="true"
      app:singleSelection="true" />
```

And here is the chip layout

chip_type.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     app:chipIconEnabled="true" />
```

The problem I'm facing is that the chip that was set programatically as selected `chip.isSelected = true` stays selected even after the user selects a different one through UI interaction.

What is the correct way to programatically select a default choice Chip that is a child of a ChipGroup in Android?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found my answer.

- Use `View.generateViewId()` and assign the new Id to the
  newly create chip. Then, add
- Add chip to its parent ChipGroup
- Check chip view ChipGroup using `viewBinding.typeChipGroup.check(id)`

This is the final code:

```
private fun setupTypeSelection(types: List<Trail.Type>) {

    types.forEach { type ->
        val chip = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chip_trail_type, viewBinding.typeContainer, false) as Chip

        chip.id = View.generateViewId()
        /* Set chip details as usual */

        viewBinding.typeContainer.addView(chip)

        if (currentType == null) viewBinding.typeChipGroup.check(chip.id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

currentType == null condition will be false for next selection. Are you making it null anywhere else?

Use ChipGroup's setOnCheckedChangeListener to check the state of chip selection instead of chip.setOnClickListener

Comment: currentType is initialised as null, so when the first chip is created, the currentType is set to its type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out setOnCheckedChangeListener. That unfortunately, doesn't answer my original question

Answer (score 0):

```
val chipGroup = findViewById<ChipGroup>(R.id.chip_group)
val tileSize320 = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.tile_size320)
chipGroup.check(tileSize320)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.